# Send xml info as a form

Tags: php, html, xml

I have an html page where the user is asked to enter in various information
then i use a php page to turn that info into an xml file and I would like to send the xml code as a FORM..

How will I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use cURL to post the XML to any uri. You can see an example in the PHP manual: http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#98628

If you really want to submit it as a form, you could output a new form after combining all data to XML, with the xml in a hidden input-field, and auto-submitting that using javascript. Though I believe the first option will be what you need :p

Comment: For the first method... I want to send it to sellonline.canadapost.ca:3000 can you please show me in coding

Comment: You could basically use the function in the link provided and call it like this:

    curl_post('sellonline.canadapost.ca:3000', array('xml' => $yourXmlData));

Comment: Can you plz explain the array('xml' => $yourxmldata));

Comment: It's the xml content you described you're composing based upon the information entered

Comment: all of the code? like if i had $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$sxe->addAttribute('type', 'documentary');

$movie = $sxe->addChild('movie');
$movie->addChild('title', 'PHP2: More Parser Stories');
$movie->addChild('plot', 'This is all about the people who make it work.');

$characters = $movie->addChild('characters');
$character  = $characters->addChild('character');
$character->addChild('name', 'Mr. Parser');
$character->addChild('actor', 'John Doe');

$rating = $movie->addChild('rating', '5');
$rating->addAttribute('type', 'stars');


all that would be after the => ??